# Handling Dynamic Image click using Selenium Webderiver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working on image click functionality where images change dynamically but the XPath remains the same.

For example:

First image inspect element:

```
<a id="adlink" target="_top" href="http://www.jimhayes.com/lennielw/index-2.html">
<img id="adimage" src="http://egranary/adverts/Images/lightwire.png" border="0"></a>
```

First image XPath:

```
//*[@id="adimage"]
```

Second image inspect element:

```
<a id="adlink" target="_top" href="http://www.lifewater.ca/index.html">
<img id="adimage" src="http://egranary/adverts/Images/lifewater1.png" border="0"></a>
```

Second image XPath:

```
//*[@id="adimage"]
```

In this example source and target are changing constantly to redirect to particular page when clicked on image.

How to handle this situation using selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirement is to basically check if the links are working fine - not broken.

In that case, I would suggest you to follow this approach - (It is in Java - you can do something similar in other languages as well)

I am trying to extract all `href` on the page. But if you want an specific xpath just change it here.

```
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com");

Map<Integer, List<String>> map = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href]")) 
                .stream()                             // find all elements which has href attribute & process one by one
                .map(ele -> ele.getAttribute("href")) // get the value of href
                .map(String::trim)                    // trim the text
                .distinct()                           // there could be duplicate links , so find unique
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LinkUtil::getResponseCode)); // group the links based on the response code
```

Now we could access the urls based on the response code we are interested in.

```
map.get(200) // will contain all the good urls
map.get(403) // will contain all the 'Forbidden' urls   
map.get(404) // will contain all the 'Not Found' urls   
map.get(0) // will contain all the unknown host urls
```

Check [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-find-broken-links-on-a-page/) for complete implementation.

Comment: Thanks Vins. Checking Broken images and links would be my next part of testing.

Comment: In above example i have given, I need to verify page redirect after image click. 
for e.g  when clicked on image A - redirects to website A. When clicked on image B -redirects to website B. And these images are changing constantly at same location(xpath). I need to test when i click on perticular image whether it redirects to the respective website.

My question is how to click on image and test page redirect when these images changes continuously.

Comment: @SheetalShahare, you do not click. instead we grab the url and hit using the `LinkUtil` - see if it works. the above method checks for all the links on a page. try this method for your site once. check this site for the complete code. http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-find-broken-links-on-a-page/